# npm install error EADDRINUSE on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, firebase

I'm using npm to install `firebase-tools`on Windows 7 and I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\Txell>npm install -g firebase-tools
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "firebase-tools"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code EADDRINUSE
npm ERR! errno EADDRINUSE
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! connect EADDRINUSE 185.31.19.162:443 - Local (undefined:undefined)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Txell\npm-debug.log
```

The npm-debug.log shows:

```
1260 verbose afterAdd C:\Users\Txell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\uuid\2.0.2\package\package.json written
1261 verbose about to build C:\Users\Txell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools
1262 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\Txell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\firebase-tools-246a529772905b3d.lock for C:\Users\Txell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools
1263 verbose stack Error: connect EADDRINUSE 185.31.19.162:443 - Local (undefined:undefined)
1263 verbose stack     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
1263 verbose stack     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
1263 verbose stack     at connect (net.js:849:16)
1263 verbose stack     at net.js:984:7
1263 verbose stack     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:64:16)
1263 verbose stack     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:83:10)
1264 verbose cwd C:\Users\Txell
1265 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
1266 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "firebase-tools"
1267 error node v4.4.3
1268 error npm  v2.15.1
1269 error code EADDRINUSE
1270 error errno EADDRINUSE
1271 error syscall connect
1272 error connect EADDRINUSE 185.31.19.162:443 - Local (undefined:undefined)
1273 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
1273 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
1274 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I'm not sure what's going on. I don't recognize the ip and I have no any service listening on 443 port.

Comment: I'm using netstat to see if some process is listening on por 443 and there aren't. In fact I don't understand why npm needs 443 port for install a package.

Comment: There appears to be [an open issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11448) related to this. Also, [a previous Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470551/npm-install-g-package-error-eaddrinuse).